# how to over come these exceptions?

Tags: php, git, zend-framework, netbeans, xampp

Music store Deployed on zend frame work , after deploying from git repository I get these errors

These errors are way too many and i am a noob with frameworks . please help me !!!

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>        'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module
>        (Application) could not be initialized.' in
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\albumzend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php
>        on line 189 ( ! ) Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException:
>        Module (Application) could not be initialized. in
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\albumzend\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php
>        on line 189 Call Stack
>        #    Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0010  135312  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0 2    0.0270  266752  Zend\Mvc\Application::init(
>        )    ..\index.php:17
>        3    0.1630  1117408 Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModules(
>        )    ..\Application.php:252
>        4    0.1630  1117592 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger(
>        )    ..\ModuleManager.php:109
>        5    0.1630  1117776 Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(
>        )    ..\EventManager.php:207 6   0.1670  1131560 call_user_func (
>        )    ..\EventManager.php:468
>        7    0.1670  1131576 Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(
>        )    ..\EventManager.php:468
>        8    0.1670  1131912 Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule(
>        )    ..\ModuleManager.php:90
>        9    0.1670  1132064 Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(
>        )    ..\ModuleManager.php:163

**MY APPLICATION.PHP**

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Musicstore',

    ),

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        //'config_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        //'config_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        //'module_map_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        //'module_map_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        //'cache_dir' => $stringPath,

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ),

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    //'service_listener_options' => array(
    //     array(
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ),
    // )

   // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
   // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
   // 'service_manager' => array(),
);
```

**INDEX.PHP module>musicstore>ablums>index.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

// directory setup and class loading

set_include_path('.' . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/library/'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/application/models/albums'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/application/forms/albums'
     . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

include "Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php";
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->registerNamespace('Models');
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);

$view = new Zend_View();
$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
$viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer();
$viewRenderer->setView($view);
Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

// load configuration
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/application/config.ini', 'general');
$registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
$registry->set('config', $config);

// setup database
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->db);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
$registry->set('db', $db);

// setup controller
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$frontController->throwExceptions(true);
$frontController->setControllerDirectory('/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/application/controllers');

Zend_Layout::startMvc(array('layoutPath'=>'/xampp/htdocs/albumzend/application/layouts'));

// run!
$frontController->dispatch();
?>
```

**MY APPLICATION**

```
module>musicstore>application>configs>Application.ini
[production]

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0

phpSettings.display_errors = 0

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "xampp/htdocs/albumzend/library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

File Struct:

http://i58.tinypic.com/2uqcbpv.png

Git Repository : https://github.com/srish/Music-Store.git

Comment: Don't quesstion on comment. put that comment in question

Comment: Question title is too long

Comment: edited the description. Sorry im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

In your git i dont see public directory with index.php file that initiates the zend-framework application, i see you mover it to the albums/index.php but there once more its not the file given by automatic project generator for zend-framework 1.12

I have one idea for you. Download the newest ZF 1 (now its 1.12, not 1.8 from 2008 year) and then try recreating your project once more. It will work better as there were several huge changes in performance and even framework that have huge positive impact.

PS:  in the index.php file that initiates the ZF - you should not make any changes. Try to make them in Bootstrap.php in application directory.